# Inncorect request URL PHPUnit functional test Symfony 4.2

Tags: symfony4, functional-testing, phpunit

I can not run the functional test I still get info:

The /blog public URL loads correctly.
Failed asserting that 500 is identical to 200.

As I checked with debug $client-> request('GET', $url) creates the address http://localhost/blog is incorrect page address. The correct page address is http: //project.local/blog or http://localhost/project/public/blog

```
  class PagesControllerTest extends WebTestCase
    {
        public function testShowPost()
        {
            $client = static::createClient();
            $client->request('GET', '/blog');
            $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
        }
```

phpunit.xml.dist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.5/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <server name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="App\Kernel" />
        <server name="HOSTNAME" value="http://project.local" />
        <env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="/foobar/" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <listeners>
        <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener" />
        <listener class="\DAMA\DoctrineTestBundle\PHPUnit\PHPUnitListener" />
    </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: It seems the problem is not within the test. 500 code means there is a server side error. Your test successfully requests `/blog`, but it responds with 500 code. Check response body and/or your PHP logs to see what is causing the error.

Comment: @d3jn

test.log: 
`request.INFO: Matched route "blog". {"route":"blog","route_parameters":{"_route":"blog","_controller":"App\\Controller\\BlogController::blog"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/blog","method":"GET"} []`

_controller is correct but request_uri is inncorect. If I enter the address http://localhost/blog through the browser, I get a 404 error

Comment: @d3jn
I am not sure if this is the error, but it throws 500. For funcional tests I did not attach or configure any additional databases
`An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS name_2, t0.slug AS slug_3 FROM blog_categories t0':

SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected (500 Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Your problem is that from testing environment there is no database selected in Symfony. Your PHPUnit testcase class must initialize it properly during the `setUp` stage (either real or a mocked one). But don't worry, you are using a framework, so I bet they already have this stuff covered and have out-of-the-box solutions. [Maybe try reading here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html)

Comment: @d3jn You were right I missed `<env name="DATABASE_URL" value="mysql://USERNAME:PASSWORD@127.0.0.1/DB_NAME" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create .env.test this file will be loaded after .env file and override environment variables for your test environment.

`DATABASE_URL=sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/data/database_test.sqlite`

Answer (score 0):

First of all print out the error by

```
$client = static::createClient();    
$client->catchExceptions(false);
```

Then, in your case it seems that your DB in testing is not exists as it shown below

```
An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'database_test'
```

you have two options:

1. Create new database for your testing
2. remove **dbname_suffix** in your db test which is responsible for giving suffix name for new database test -at
   *config/packages/test/doctrine.yaml* -